# Whats is the correct way to save and retrieve an entry or assets in a custom record?

Tags: plugin-development, relations, records

Let's say i have a custom `ActiveRecord` and want to save a single `Asset` or an `Entry` relation (one to one) inside one of it's columns, what's the correct way to do this?